# Changing text with .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

## Problem

I'm trying to change the text on a series of `<div>` by using `.each` to grab data from an array. When I `console.log`, I can see the data displayed appropriately. But the actual buttons all display `Header 4` and `Subtitle 4`

### scripts.js

```
  $.each(steps, function(index) {
    $(".map__step--headline").html(steps[index].header);
    $(".map__step--subtitle").html(steps[index].subtitle);
    console.log(steps[index].header);
    console.log(steps[index].subtitle);
  });
```

### steps.js

```
var steps = [
  {
    "header": "Header 1",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle 1"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 2",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle 2"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 3",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle 3"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 4",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle 4"
  }
]
```

### index.html

```
<div class="map__navigation">
            <div class="map__step is-selected" data-id="1">
                <p class="map__step--headline">tk-headline</p>
                <p class="map__step--subtitle">tk-subtitle</p>
            </div>

            <div class="map__step" data-id="2">
                <p class="map__step--headline">tk-headline</p>
                <p class="map__step--subtitle">tk-subtitle</p>
            </div>

            <div class="map__step" data-id="3">
                <p class="map__step--headline">tk-headline</p>
                <p class="map__step--subtitle">tk-subtitle</p>
            </div>

            <div class="map__step is-last" data-id="4">
                <p class="map__step--headline">tk-headline</p>
                <p class="map__step--subtitle">tk-subtitle</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Tha's because you are changing the text to all buttons each iteration. On the 1st step of the loop, all the buttons have Header 1, on the 2nd Header 2, and so on...

Comment: I don't get it... What are you expecting to see ?

Comment: @KobyDouek I am expecting to see `Header 1`, `Subtitle 1` on so on ... for each of the buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like this instead:

```
$('.map__step').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var index = $this.data('id') - 1;
  $('.map__step--headline', this).html(steps[index].header);
  $('.map__step--subtitle', this).html(steps[index].subtitle);
});
```

Rather than trying to use the array directly to populate the html, let the html determine what it wants from the array.

So we pull a list of the elements we're interested in and iterate over them, using their `data-id` attributes to index into the array to get the data they want.

Comment: first value of each´s callback-function gives you also the index

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @mr.void It's also potentially the wrong index. There's nothing that says the `data-id` has to be sequential.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) can accept a function, you can calculate the actual string to return based on the index of each `<div>` in the iteration:

```
function getHeadline(i) {
    return steps[i].header;
}

function getSubtitle(i) {
    return steps[i].subtitle;
}

$('.map__step--headline').html(getHeadline);
$('.map__step--subtitle').html(getSubtitle);
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/me0a4mum/)